# check-db returns duplicate key error on a unique index, however select query returns only 1 value

Tags: sql-server

After getting some inconsistency errors, I did a check db on my database and got some unique index errors. Tried to locate the duplicate rows, however select query returns only 1 value. I have absolutely no idea now. What could be the problem here?

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement
>   terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name
>   'dbo.INVENTTRANSPOSTING' and
>
> the index name 'I_553DATEVOUCHERTRANSIDX'. The duplicate key value is
>   (5637144576, ers, Aug 31 2016 12:00AM, SFT0017855,
>
> 22567183763, 1).

And i query the table with those values and i get only 1 record.

Comment: Ockham's Razor would point to your query :-) Please show some code

Comment: please show error message and schema of table involved

Comment: Well,dynamics ax manages the db,so there isn't any code

Comment: *And i query the table with those values and i get only 1 record*: Please show the query you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the IDENTITY seed has the wrong value. For example, the primary key of the row is '1', and the IDENTITY SEED on the table is also '1', then the INSERT of a new row would try to insert the same primary key value, which is not allowed. You can get the IDENTITY SEED with:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, IDENT_SEED(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME) AS IDENT_SEED, IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME) AS IdentCurrent
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE IDENT_SEED(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME) IS NOT NULL;
```

and then you should set the IDENTITY SEED to the correct value.

Comment: well,the problem is not about inserting,the database is inconsistent and somehow a unique key is duplicated...